# background image position

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i want position my background image in the bottom right of my page :

```
.bg{
  background-image: url("Wave.png");
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 85%;
  background-position: bottom 0px right 0px;
  background-origin: content-box;
}
```

The bg class is the global container of my html

```
<body class="background">


     <div class="bg">

     </div>
</div
```

when there is not much content in the page i have no problem it is displayed correctly

[image]

but when there is more rows in my table i have this problem

[image]

any ideas please i can't figure out what's wrong ?

Comment: you have put position: absolute; but no bottom:0; and right:0? Maybe thats the problem?

Comment: try `right: 0` and `bottom: 0`. Also, for `.background` add `position: relative`

Comment: Reference point for absolute positioning is the viewport, if no positioned ancestor element exists. So your `height:100%` does not apply to the actual height of body, if you don’t at least position that one relative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.bg{
    background: url("Wave.png") no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: bottom;
}
```

EDIT:

```
<body>
     <div class="bg">
        <div>
            ...
        </div>
     </div>
</body>
```

Some explanations:
Setting `background-attachment: fixed` makes the background fixed on the page when you scroll.
The content should then be restricted within the div by setting `overflow-y: scroll;` so that, in your case where you have a table that can be longer than the div, the table will be constrained inside the div with scrolling enabled, and it won't extend outside the div.

background-position: bottom is also enough.

I notice the closing tag for your body element is a `</div` that is not enclosed properly. You should change the `</div` to `</body>`. If you already closed the body in your full code, you can remove the unnecessary `</div`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.bg{
  background-image: url("Wave.png");
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-origin: content-box;
}
```